# Java Object Conversion to Integer and String wrapper

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a `java.lang.Object` return type from a function.  I want to verify whatever `Object` value returned is of numeric type (`double` or `long` or `int` or `byte` or `Double` or `Long` or `Byte` or `Float` or `Double` ....) and if it's true want to convert into a Integer wrapper reference type. Also if the `Object` instance holds a `String` value I want it to be stored in a String reference.

Comment: Do you have a question ?

Answer (score 4):

> *Have a `Object` return type from a function. I want to verify whatever Object value returned is of numeric type(double or long or int or byte or Double or Long or Byte or Float or Double ....)*

```
if (obj instanceof Number)
    ...
```

> *if it's true want to convert into a Integer wrapper reference type*

```
if ...
    val = (Integer) ((Number) obj).intValue();
```

> *Also If the Object instance holds a String value i want it to be stored in a String reference.*

```
...
else if (obj instanceof String)
    val = obj;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Notice Valueof function take string as argument. when it is called with a int value does java implicitly convert to string or do i need to toString of the intvalue?   If i need to identify a  number is with decimal digits is it sufficient to check instanceof float or Double ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Not sure whether my earlier query was clear.  How do i identify whether the number is with decimal digits?  for example how do i identify number with decimal digit 12.23f,  0.789

Comment: Try parsing it using Double.valueOf. If it throws an exception it's not a double.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
Object obj = getProcessedObject();
if(obj instanceof Number) {
    // convert into a Integer wrapper reference type
Integer ref1 = ((Number)obj).intValue();
}
if(obj instanceof String) {
// process object for String
String ref = (String)obj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Notice Valueof function take string as argument. when it is called with a int value does java implicitly convert to string or do i need to toString of the intvalue? If i need to identify a number is with decimal digits is it sufficient to check instanceof float or Double ?

Answer (score 0):

A method that returns Object cannot return primitive types like double, long, or int.

You can check for the actual returned type using instanceof:

```
if (object instanceof Number){
    // want to convert into a Integer wrapper reference type
    object = ((Number)object).intValue();  // might lose precision
}
```

You can assign to a String variable by type-casting

```
if (object instanceof String){
   stringVariable = (String)object;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Notice Valueof function take string as argument. when it is called with a int value does java implicitly convert to string or do i need to toString of the intvalue? If i need to identify a number is with decimal digits is it sufficient to check instanceof float or Double ?

Answer (score 0):

Although you probably have a serious design problem, in order to achieve what you want you can use instanceof operator or getClass() method:

```
Object o = myFunction();
if(o instanceof Integer) { //or if o.getClass() == Integer.class if you want 
                       only objects of that specific class, not the superclasses
   Integer integer = (Integer) o;
   int i = integer.intValue();
}
   //do your job with the integer
if(o instanceof String)
   //String job
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.   If i need to identify a number is with decimal digits is it sufficient to check instanceof float or Double ?